# How can I determine if, and which of, my iCloud photos are shared?

Tags: iphone

When I try to turn off Shared Albums, my iPhone 12 Pro warns

> Turning off Shared Albums will delete all shared photos from your iPhone.

Hence, I need backup all shared photos first.

Isn't [léonie's answer dated July 27 2016](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7621850?sortBy=best) outdated ? Under "iCloud Photos", I see no "Shared" tab.

> Any shared album you shared will show in the "Shared" section of your Photos Library, if you enable
> Photos > Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Photo Sharing.
> Then you will see any albums appear in the "Shared" tab of our Library or in the "Shared" section of the Sidebar.
> IF there are no albums in that section, you did not create any. For example, I am having four shared albums.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see all shared albums in your iPhone go to Photos > Albums > Shared Albums > See All

Under album name there is information who created it: "Created by You" or "Created by [name here]".

[Save photos and videos from a shared album to your Photos library](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/add-delete-photos-videos-a-shared-album-iph10caf6f49/17.0/ios/17.0#iphaf57b9274):

1. Open the Photos app  on your iPhone.
2. Tap Albums, tap the shared album, then tap a photo or video.
3. Tap the Share button, swipe up, then tap Save Image or Save Video.